# RegEx in Javascript returning Null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate Youtube URLs using a javascript snippet. 
Here is the code i am using:

```
var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xldcf8_XVfQ";
var regEx = new RegExp("(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?((www\.)youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)(\/watch\?v=)(\w{11})");
var checkRegEx = tabUrl.match(regEx);
```

This alway returns me null even for valid urls which should be matched. However my regex is valid which i checked up at: 
http://regexr.com/3aj3r

Trying to output using :

```
    document.getElementById("yDivElem").innerHTML = checkRegEx;
```

Comment: You need to escape all the backslashes in the string. Why don't you just use a regexp literal instead of `new RegExp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your regex without the RegEx object.

```
var re = /(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?((www\.)youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)(\/watch\?v=)(\w{11})/; 
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xldcf8_XVfQ';

var match = re.exec(url);
```

edit: As @Barmer said, you'll need to double escape your string when using the RegEx object.

```
var regEx = new RegExp("(http\\:\\/\\/|https\\:\\/\\/)?((www\\.)youtube\\.com|youtu\\.?be)(\\/watch\\?v=)(\\w{11})");
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the basic forms.

```
 # raw: (https?://)?((www\.)youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)(/watch\?v=)(\w{11})
 # quoted: "(https?://)?((www\\.)youtube\\.com|youtu\\.?be)(/watch\\?v=)(\\w{11})"
 # delimited:  /(https?:\/\/)?((www\.)youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)(\/watch\?v=)(\w{11})/

 # raw formatted:

 ( https?:// )?                # (1)
 (                             # (2 start)
      ( www\. )                     # (3)
      youtube\.com
   |  youtu\.?be
 )                             # (2 end)
 ( /watch\?v= )                # (4)
 ( \w{11} )                    # (5)
```